# Why udisks is not in the system

Tags: 14.04, mount, nautilus, udisks

In Ubuntu manual regarding [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) is described that Nautilus is using udisks to mount partitions. But when I type `udisks` in terminal system tells that I need to install it. So, do Nautilus really uses udisks?

```
"When you mount a disc normally with the file browser (nautilus etc) it mounts disks by interacting with udisks behind the scenes."
```

Answer (score 8):

In Trusty `udisks2` is installed by [default](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest) and used by nautilus.

The binary is in

```
/usr/bin/udisksctl
```

found via `dpkg -L udisks2 | grep bin/`

---

from `man udisksctl`

```
NAME
       udisksctl - The udisks command line tool

SYNOPSIS
       udisksctl status

       udisksctl info {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE}

       udisksctl mount {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--filesystem-type TYPE] [--options OPTIONS...] [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl unmount {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--force] [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl unlock {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl lock {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl loop-setup --file PATH [--read-only] [--offset OFFSET] [--size SIZE] [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl loop-delete {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl power-off {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl smart-simulate --file PATH {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--no-user-interaction]

       udisksctl monitor

       udisksctl dump

       udisksctl help
```

---

*Here is a short test*

```
% sudo apt-get remove udisks2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  arronax arronax-nautilus brasero deja-dup-backend-gvfs gnome-disk-utility
  gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sushi gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-backends-goa
  gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-share software-center
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop udisks2 usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 20,9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

```
% sudo apt-get remove udisks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  udisks
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1.043 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: is it possible to use  udisks2 command from terminal then? I can't find such command

Comment: @vico `/usr/bin/udisksctl` found via `dpkg -L udisks2 | grep bin/`

Comment: the problem is that various ubuntu wikis and advice sites still tell people to use udisks and there is no message indicating where it went.

Comment: This is not correct `udisksctl` is a completely different command from `udisks`. It's not a drop in replacement.

Comment: `/usr/bin/udisks` is NOT available in Ubuntu 18.  `udisks` performs many functions unavailable from `udisksctl`.  I didn't find a "`udisks2`" command.  It is becoming clear that we need to know what package the actual `udisks` command is IN.

Answer (score 5):

I was using udisks to mount an NTFS partition on the same disk as the Operating System.  My command looked like this

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

I used this command in 16.04 (mint 18):

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Comment: thanks Nick. funny thing is you cant use 'sudo', or it will mount under /media/root instead of media/user. have to run it and use the custom 'authentication' thing instead